# how to get the email id from user in asterisk dialplan

Tags: asterisk

Is there a way or application to get the email id from user in asterisk dialplan without 
using voice mail? actually i want to register user on the basis of email id but i don't 
know how can i get the email id from user during the ivr call. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use an AGI to do a database look-up based on caller-id or based on user DTMF input, like an account code.  From there, you would retrieve the user record from your database, and you could work with it.

Asterisk itself does not know what an email address is.  You need to hold that information externally.

That said, something like ruby/rails for your website to get the customer signed up with their email address, and then ruby/adhearsion to manage the call and hold the user record during the call works really well.  I've done that for a few customers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, asterisk can only know details about the incoming call if they are provided in the incoming SIP request, typically in the INVITE, and typically in the headers part. If you can somehow program the user's phone(s) to provide the  caller's "email id" (i assume you meant "email address") as an INVITE header, you can obtain the header's value in the dialplan with the [SIP_HEADER](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+sip_header) function. Otherwise, as Michel suggests, you will have to get what you need from an external database that associates the user's caller ID with their "email id".